# Rails 3 request dispatch cycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I was looking at the rails 3 architecture in order to understand the process of dispatching a request . The whole process is quite simple. Application is a rack application which finally delegates its call message to the call method of ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet which dispatches appropriate action of necessary controller. It takes controller and action names from the hash stored in rack env by the key "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters".

So the question is: Who sets this hash? Who parses request uri and determines action and controller names?

I was not able to find this code. I see that during route configuration ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper object is used to construct information about defined routes and stores it in ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet. But how this information is used during the request to find appropriate action and controller. Is rack also somehow involved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"action_dispatch.request.path_parameters" is stored as the constant `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::PARAMETERS_KEY` (actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb)

`PARAMETERS_KEY` is used later on in that same file and passed into the constructer for `::Rack::Mount::RouteSet`

Going to `::Rack::Mount::RouteSet` source here: https://github.com/josh/rack-mount/blob/master/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb#L22 you can see that attribute name is stored.

Same file, down in the `call(env`) method which is of course the Rack interface that will be called into, we see this line ( https://github.com/josh/rack-mount/blob/master/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb#L147 ) where your `env["action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"]` attribute is actually set, and eventually returned back into the code you were investigating.

Hope this helps!