# How to route and render (dispatch) from a model in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to dispatch (route and render) from a model. (I only care about `GET` requests and I ignore `Accept:` headers, so I only look at `PATH_INFO`.)

```
# app/models/response.rb
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  # col :path_info
  # col :app_version
  # col :body, :type => :text

  def set_body
    params = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path_info, :method => :get)
    controller = "#{params[:controller].camelcase}Controller".constantize.new
    controller.action_name = params[:action]
    controller.request = ActionDispatch::Request.new('rack.input' => [])
    controller.request.path_parameters = params.with_indifferent_access
    controller.request.format = params[:format] || 'html'
    controller.response = ActionDispatch::Response.new
    controller.send params[:action]
    self.body = controller.response.body
  end
end
```

The above code **works**, but it feels clunky. What's the right way to do it? I'm imagining [Yehuda Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122162/yehuda-katz) would tell me something like:

```
def set_body
  # [...]
  app = "#{params[:controller].camelcase}Controller".constantize.action(params[:action])
  app.process params
  self.body = app.response.body
end
```

FWIW here's my routes file:

```
# config/routes.rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :products                                       # GET /products.json?merchant_id=foobar
  match '/:id(.:format)' => 'contents#show', :via => 'get'  # GET /examples
  root :to => 'contents#index', :via => 'get'               # GET /
end
```

See also: *[Rails 3 request dispatch cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416391/rails-3-request-dispatch-cycle)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually even easier than that:

```
session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
session.get(path_info)
self.body = session.response.body
```